# Tidyeval in a non-quasiquotation context (psych::describeBy(group))

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval, gt

I am trying to make a function that will return a `gt` table of the results of the common `psych::describe()` and `psych::describeBy()` functions.

the problem is that `describeBy()` expects the group argument to be of the form `data$vector` rather than just `group = vector`.

So

```
describeBy(data, data$group) 
# works

describeBy(data, group)
# doesn't work
```

this is fine for general use--just a thing to remember. **But to use it in a shiny app, I really need it to take the form of the second call in the above.**

### here is my function so far:

```
description<-function(data, group = NULL, fast = TRUE, ...) {
  grp<-paste0(deparse(substitute(group)))
  #print(grp)
  
  
    if(is.null(group)) {
      data %>%
        psych::describe(fast = fast, ...) %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
        dplyr::select(-c(vars)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(is.numeric, round, 2)) %>%
        gt::gt() %>%
        gt::tab_options(
          column_labels.font.size = "small",
          table.font.size = "small",
          row_group.font.size = "small",
          data_row.padding = px(3)
        ) %>% 
        tab_header(
          title = paste0("Data Description") 
        )
    } else {
      data %>%
        psych::describeBy(group = group, fast = fast, mat= TRUE, ...) %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
        select(-c(item, vars)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(is.numeric, round, 2)) %>%
        arrange(group1) %>%
        group_by(group1) %>%
        gt() %>%
        gt::tab_options(
          column_labels.font.size = "small",
          table.font.size = "small",
          row_group.font.size = "small",
          data_row.padding = px(3))
    } %>% 
    tab_header(
      title = paste0("Data Description") ,
      subtitle = paste0("Grouped by: ",  grp )
    )
}
```

I've tried a lot of variations on enquo, names(), !!, etc. in the `group =`  call, but I can't quite get it to work right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psych::describeBy` does not contain a data argument. Hence you cannot use `group` directly from the data. If you need to use that, you would better use the formula option. eg:

```
psych::describeBy(iris~Species)
```

if at all you are writing a function, then do:

```
my_describe <- function(data, group = NULL, fast = TRUE){
  if(deparse(substitute(group)) == 'NULL')
    psych::describe(data)
  else  psych::describeBy(as.formula(substitute(data~group)))
}
```

Note: Note the best way to go about it but it works

Comment: this feels like it should work but I'm still getting the `error: object 'grouping_variable' not found` error

Comment: The error is from the `gropby` in the tidyverse part. What is `group1`?

Comment: just try out the `my_describe` function that I wrote on your data. It should definitely work

Comment: `> my_describe <- function(data, group = NULL, fast = TRUE){
+   if(is.null(group))
+     psych::describe(data)
+   else  psych::describeBy(as.formula(substitute(data~group)))
+ }
> my_describe(penguins, species)
Error in my_describe(penguins, species) : object 'species' not found
`

`group1` is what the output of describeBy calls the grouping variable the user inputs; it's necessary to format it for use in `gt()`

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney it seems your data does not contain `species`. can you post `names(penguins)`?

Comment: https://github.com/allisonhorst/palmerpenguins 

It's this dataset. species is the first variable. 

`describeBy(penguins, penguins$species)` works just fine. `mydescribe()` does not.

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney i see where the problem is. Give me a second

Comment: THANK YOU so much.

Comment: @AndrewMcCartney. If this answers you question, you can accept it

Comment: yep! (but of course, now I have a new error when building it into the shiny app. because of course I do:)